# Google oauth not returning email passport authentication

Tags: node.js, express, google-oauth, passport.js

I am trying to make a sign in with google button using passport module of node js. I am trying to get person's email id, name, profile pic. I am trying to download pic to local server. Google is not returning email id even after adding 'email' to scope and nor the returned link for profile pic is working. I have looked into various answers to this question but all say to include userinfo.email. It has been deprecated now. As per google documentation new scope parameter is email.

Below is my code. Any help is appreciated.

Passport

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({

    clientID        : configAuth.googleAuth.clientID,
    clientSecret    : configAuth.googleAuth.clientSecret,
    callbackURL     : configAuth.googleAuth.callbackURL,
},
function(token, refreshToken, profile, done) {

    // make the code asynchronous
    // User.findOne won't fire until we have all our data back from Google
    process.nextTick(function() {

        // try to find the user based on their google id
        User.findOne({ 'google.id' : profile.id }, function(err, user) {
            if (err)
                return done(err);

            if (user) {

                // if a user is found, log them in
                return done(null, user);
            } else {
                // if the user isnt in our database, create a new user
                var newUser          = new User();
                console.log(profile);
                //JSON.parse(profile);
                // set all of the relevant information
                newUser.google.id    = profile.id;
                newUser.google.token = profile.token;
                newUser.google.name  = profile.displayName;
                newUser.google.uname = profile.emails[0].value; // pull the first email
                newUser.google.dp    = profile._json.picture;
                console.log('url is');
                console.log(newUser.google.name);
                console.log(newUser.google.dp);
                //console.log(profile.picture);
                Download(newUser.google.uname, newUser.google.dp,function(err){
                    if(err)
                        console.log('error in dp');
                    else
                        console.log('Profile Picture downloaded');
                });

                // save the user
                newUser.save(function(err) {
                    if (err)
                        throw err;
                    return done(null, newUser);
                });
            }
        });
    });

}));
};
```

routes.js

```
    app.get('/connect/google', passport.authorize('google', { scope : ['profile', 'email'] }));

    // the callback after google has authorized the user
    app.get('/connect/google/callback',
        passport.authorize('google', {
            successRedirect : '/profile',
            failureRedirect : '/'
        }));
```

download.js

```
    module.exports = function(username, uri, callback){
var destination;

request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream("./downloads/"+username+".png"))
.on('close', function(){
    console.log("saving process is done!");
});
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I had the same problem and wrote the scope in this way:

```
app.get('/connect/google', passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
    ]
}));
```

And you will get the email:

```
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    console.log(profile.emails[0].value);
});
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you . I got i working :)
can you please help me in fb oauth also. I have got it working but getting tokenization error. Here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38299165/how-to-use-random-guid-with-passport-module-and-express-server

Comment: did you get authorization screen everytime api tries to access user profile?

Comment: The truth is that I'm starting with this. I have to do more testing, but for now do not have that problem.
The login with Facebook I have not implemented. When I work on this, if I can, I will try to help you with your question.

Comment: Can u tell me are you getting authentication screen everytime you try to login

Comment: Not really. Look at [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20160923190904/http://www.danielgynn.com/node-auth-part2/). I think your problem may be the refresh token.

Answer (score 22):

The above answer definitely works, there is also one more way to approach this.

```
app.get('/auth/google',
  passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile', 'email'] })
);
```

In your `routes.js` with the `profile` add `email`.

This should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 6):

According to google documentation for oauth, the first parameter has to be openid and the second can be email or profile, or both

```
app.get('/auth/google',
    passport.authenticate('google', {scope: ['openid', 'email', 'profile']})
);
```

[documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#scope-param)

Answer (score 0):

Add the line of code after callbackUrl.

```
userProfileURL: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo"
```