# Passport Google oauth2 does not return email

Tags: authentication, passport.js, passport-google-oauth2

I'm trying to access user details using passport google oauth2, it returns `id`, `gender`, `displayName`, `name`, `provider` but not `email`.

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
  clientID: '1050835058852-cmniek05f0tdotj4ikp54s8qvvgbd9j4.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  clientSecret: 'LjnSZOwA95bL6hvKMYjWPc_Q',
  callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback',
  profileFields: ['id', 'email', 'gender', 'displayName', 'name', 'provider']
},
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    if (profile) {
        user = profile;
        console.log(profile);
        passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
            done(null, user);
        });
        passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
            done(null, user);
        });
        return cb(null, user);
    }
    else {
        return cb(null, false);
    }
  }
));
```

In the profile fields I have specified email, still it sends everything except email.

Here is the get request which I'm trying to get authenticated.

```
app.get('/auth/google',
    passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile'] })
);

app.get('/auth/google/callback',
  passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/auth/google' }),
  function(req, res) {
  // Successful authentication, redirect home.
  res.redirect('/account');
});
```

Comment: I suppose the silence on this question is the answer... I was wondering the same thing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google oauth not returning email passport authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38259861/google-oauth-not-returning-email-passport-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

Add email to the scope. As following:

```
scope: ['profile', 'email']
```

If it doesn't render email in the response change the scopes like this:

```
scope: [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
]
```