# Heroku Google OAuth Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, google-oauth, status

I am getting a very frustrating error. When I make the google OAuth request in my local development environment it is working perfectly. (using passport authentication). Pushing to Heroku I am getting a status 200 versus the status 302 I get in development that redirects me to the google oauth login page. The screen is just showing up blank with no errors. I have tried to intentionally put an error with the client ID, but it isn't even registering the request at all.
 [Log-In](/auth/google/) 
Brings me to a blank screen on heroku, and registers no request at all. 
Please Help!

Server-Side Passport:

```
 // .use is generic register
passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: keys.googleClientID,
      clientSecret: keys.googleClientSecret,
      // need url for where user should go on callback after they grant permission to our application on google auth page
      callbackURL: "/auth/google/callback",
      // have to authorize this callback url in the google oauth console.developors screen because of security reasons
      proxy: true // trust the proxy our request runs through so heroku callbacks to the correct url
    },
    async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      // after authenticated on the next get request to google it will call this with the accessToken, aka callback function
      // console.log("access token", accessToken);
      // console.log("refresh token", refreshToken);
      // console.log("profile", profile);

      // check to see if user id already exists before saving it to DB so it does not overlap...mongoose query...asynchronous operation
      // using async await
      const existingUser = await User.findOne({
        googleId: profile.id
      });
      // get promise response
      if (existingUser) {
        // already have record
        // finish passport auth function
        return done(null, existingUser); // passes to serialize user so serialize can pull that user id
      }
      // we don't have a new record so make one
      const user = await new User({
        // creates new model instance of user
        googleId: profile.id
      }).save(); // have to save it to DB
      // get promise from save since asynchronize, then finish with response
      done(null, user); // passes to serialize user so serialize can get that id
    }
  )
); // create new instance of GoogleStrategy
```

Server-Side API:

```
    app.get(
    "/auth/google", // passport, attempt to authenticate the user coming in on this route
    passport.authenticate("google", {
      // google strategy has internal code, that is 'google', so passport will know to find the google passport authenticator
      scope: ["profile", "email"] // options object
      // specifies to google we want access to this users profile and email information from their account, these are premade strings in the google oauth process not made up
    })
  );

  // in this callback route they are going to have the code, and google will see that and it will handle it differnetly by exchanging the code for an actual profile, it will call the next part of the GoogleStrategy, aka the accessToken to be saved to Database

  // @route GET auth/google/callback
  // @desc  Get callback data from google to redirect user if signed in
  // @access Private can only access this after signed in

  app.get(
    "/auth/google/callback",
    passport.authenticate("google"),
    // after authenticate process is done, send user to correct route
    (req, res) => {
      // redirect to dashboard route after sign-in
      res.redirect("/surveys");
      // full HTTP requrest, so it reloads versus AJAX request which uses react and redux and is much faster
    }
  );
```

Client - Side

```
<div
            className="collapse navbar-collapse nav-positioning"
            id="navbarNav"
          >
            <ul className="navbar-nav">
              <li className="nav-item google-link">
                <a className="nav-link" href="/auth/google">
                  Google Login
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
```

Index.js

```
// Route file, or starter file
const express = require("express");
// node.js does not have support from E6,
// so we use common js modules
// import vs require :
// common vs ES6

// bring in mongoose
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

// tell express it must make use of cookies when using passport
const cookieSession = require("cookie-session");
const passport = require("passport");

// pull in body-parser middleware to get req.body
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

// connect it to DB in keys so it is not posted to github
const keys = require("./config/keys");

//connect mongoose
mongoose.connect(keys.mongoURI);

// ########## MODELS ################
// THIS MUST BE ABOVE WHERE YOU USE IT, SO ABOVE PASSPORT
require("./models/User");
require("./models/Survey");
// don't have to require recipient because its included inside Survey

// pull in passport service, we are not returning anything in passport, so we do not need const passport because nothing to assign
require("./services/passport");

// Generate a new application that represents a running express app
const app = express(); // vast majority use single app
// this will listen for incoming requests, and route them on to different route handlers

// parser so every time a req has a req.body comes in then it will be assigned to the req.body property
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(
  cookieSession({
    // age for auth cookies to last... 30 days
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    // give cookie a key
    keys: [keys.cookieKey]
  })
);

// tell passport to use cookies
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
// done with authentication flow

//require that file returns a function, which is then immediately called with the app object
require("./routes/authRoutes")(app);
require("./routes/billingRoutes")(app);
require("./routes/surveyRoutes")(app);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  // if in production make sure express will serve up production assets
  // like main.js
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));

  // Express will serve up index.html file if it doesn't recognize the routes
  const path = require("path");

  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}

// dynamically figure out what port to listen to... Heroku, heroku will inject env variables in moment of deploy, but only works in production not development environment
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000; // if heroku port exists assign it that, else, assign it 5000

app.listen(PORT); // listen for requests and route them to the correct handler on port 5000

/* ###### HEROKU PREDEPLOY ##### */
// specifiy node version and start script for heroku in package.json
// make .gitignore for dependencies which should not be committed on deploy, heroku will install them itself

// app.use wires up middleware for our application

// ############### TIPS
/*
 Google first, because its been asked before...
 Run in module
 */
```

Comment: Can you please post your client side code and server side API for `/auth/google` ?

Comment: sorry for the delay, posted

Comment: Are you google client keys configured to work with the heroku domain?

Comment: yes they are...even if they weren't I would be getting an authorization error? It's just bringing me to a blank screen. Again, this works correctly on local, but not heroku. Could I be missing a production setting?

Comment: you´ll need to go into browser devtools and look at the network tab to see what is happening

Comment: @pinoyyid I did just that and the request is going through with status 200. But it is not going to the google authorized login. Heroku Logs is also not registering a request to the backend api. could their be something wrong with my front-end? Proxy?

Comment: there will be a number of http fetches. you need to preserve logs between pages and note where the requests are going and what the responses are.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue with this problem too. I solve it by define an absoluteURI on the config keys. because google look at url callback at https:// and heroku path is http:// which it should be fix when you add proxy: true but it is not.

On the config keys add

dev: absoluteURI: localhost:5000

prod: absoluteURI: http://herokupath

```
// .use is generic register
passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: keys.googleClientID,
      clientSecret: keys.googleClientSecret,
      callbackURL: absoluteURI + "/auth/google/callback",
      proxy: true 
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that your app on heroku is only listening for http requests. If your link to the OAuth page has the form "https://your-domain.com/auth/google", then your app's routes will not match against that route (because of the https) and so your app will show a blank page, just like it will show for any route that it's not listening for.

One way to get around this problem and still use https (and therefore still show the secure logo next to the url) is to use https for every link except for this OAuth link. Your get and post requests within the app will be using http, but any link visible on the url will use https. Something like this would work:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
            const reqType = req.headers["x-forwarded-proto"];
            // if not https redirect to https unless logging in using OAuth
            if (reqType !== "https") {
                req.url.indexOf("auth/google") !== -1
                  ? next()
                  : res.redirect("https://" + req.headers.host + req.url);
            } 
        } else {
            next();
        }
    });
```

And any frontend link that points to the OAuth login page should be an http link

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look  at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38412267/3397712). It looks like your scope params need to be modified for the google auth to work.

Comment: see the comment below that answer, which is another way to set the scopes. I will test this method, maybe they worked in development but not in heroku.

Comment: still not working, I am not sure what is going on because the error is not showing.

Comment: it almost seems as if it is not even hitting my api request